# I need Report output in csv while scheduling report, I tried with different ways but csv output comes with merge cells. How can I get resolve this?

Tags: oracle, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-fusion-apps, oracle-integration-cloud

I need Report output in csv while scheduling report, I tried with different ways but csv output comes with merge cells. How can I get resolve this ?

Comment: You can demonstrate the problem of generating a csv file and merging cells.

Comment: Can you let us know what is the expected output and what you are getting?